# MVP addon for Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, mvp, vaadin7, add-on

Our application uses Vaadin 6 and we are planning to migrate it to Vaadin 7.
We used the following addon for MVP design...
https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/mvp4vaadin

Unfortunately, vaadin 7 is not supported by this addon.

**Is there any other MVP addon available which supports Vaadin 7 ?**
Ideally with minimal change in code.

We are kind of got stuck with our migration as this MVP addon is the basic design/model in our application.
Kindly respond.

Thank you